# Data Export of SQL Server table from one server to another / Data Flow task error

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am trying to export the data from pre-prod to prod server but somehow it is failing.

Right Click-> Task -> Export -> Source -Destination, choose table

Dropping and recreating of the table is not possible on production I believe because it has already 300,000 data records on prod.

How can I amend the records from pre-prod (600,000 records) to prod?

Any help greatly appreciated

[Error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhYZB.jpg)

Comment: It clearly states *Violation of Primary key constraint*. You have duplicate data in your source.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Edit Mappings` page when `Select Source Tables and Views` before you hit the `finish` button , check `Append rows to the destination table` and check `Enable identity insert` if you have: 1.identity column in your destination table ; 2.Would like to append the 600K rows not overwrite the original 300K; Otherwise you have to take care of the source data to see whether it violates the target table schema, such as `NULL` is accepted or not and so on.

Comment: Thank you for answer but already following the steps, edit mapping,append rows to destination table and enable identity insert. still getting error as per the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this situation would be to

```
select * into preprodtable_bak from preprodtable
```

Then clean preprodtable_bak from any records that already exist in prod table(using range of id's maybe) or any duplicates.

Then export data from the preprodtable_bak table.

Comment: I tried Off constraint and PK...
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"     no help